# pull data from a Datagridview in vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

I have my datagridview and i want to pass that info into a datatable or another place, i'm trying this

```
 Dim dt As DataTable
    dt = CType(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable)
```

But i only get null, any ideas? I don't know how to get the info from the datagridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution, it's a bit dirty but... it works for me

```
  Dim valor As Integer
    valor = DataGridView1.RowCount
    valor = valor - 2

    For indice As Integer = 0 To valor
        ' DataGridView1.Item(0, indice).Value.ToString()
        ' DataGridView1.Item(1, indice).Value.ToString()
        ' in my case i only have two colums but if tyou have more you can use double for
    Next
```

Hope this help somebody :)

Comment: you can fill easily your datatable or anything you need... Good luck to everybody

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.
`dt = TryCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable)`
Or

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt = (DirectCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable))
```

Or

Use following function to get Datatable from Grid

```
public DataTable DataGridView2DataTable(DataGridView dgv, String tblName, int minRow=0){

  DataTable dt = new DataTable(tblName);

  // Header columns
  foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgv.Columns)
  {
    DataColumn dc = new DataColumn(column.Name.ToString());
    dt.Columns.Add(dc);
  }

  // Data cells
  for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
    DataGridViewRow row = dgv.Rows[i];
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    for (int j = 0; j < dgv.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
      dr[j] = (row.Cells[j].Value == null) ? "" : row.Cells[j].Value.ToString();
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
  }

  // Related to the bug arround min size when using ExcelLibrary for export
  for (int i = dgv.Rows.Count; i < minRow; i++)
  {
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
      dr[j] = "  ";
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
  }
  return dt;
}
```